# Save register database current date change it

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

When save some register the current date save with one day more, for example: current date: 2023-01-18 and save 2023-01-19

i use nodejs and moment()

i try this code
`let fecha4 = moment().local().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"); console.log(req.body.length); let fecha = moment().utcOffset("GMT-4").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"); console.log(fecha4, "Fecha Normal", fecha);`

Comment: Where does it save?

Comment: SqlServer database, MongoDB, that happen in the night, in day all is ok, save register on the same date, but pas 6 pm, save register date diferent date.